# How to construct a linear feedback shift register

Tags: recursion

Are there any posts regarding the construction of a LFSR (Linear Feedback Shift Register) in *Mathematica*? I can't seem to find any and I am not sure how I would construct one.

Comment: Never use unexplained acronyms unless you're sure every reader knows the meaning ahead of time.

Comment: Expanded on the acronym. Thanks

Comment: The [package here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5717/) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are any built-in methods, but here is a basic implementation of a small one:

```
scramble = BitXor[#3, #4] &;

step[previous_] := ReplacePart[
   RotateRight[previous],
   {1 -> scramble @@ previous}];

Nest[step, {1, 0, 1, 1}, 5]
```

This gives the result after 5 steps. You can use something like the following to plot the sequence:

```
ListPlot[FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ NestList[step, {1, 0, 1, 1}, 50], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

And check the coverage:

```
DeleteDuplicates[NestList[step, {1, 0, 1, 1}, 50]] // Length
```

15

---

To make a "stateful" version, you can do this:

```
makeLFSR[] := Module[{state, nextState},
   state = {1, 0, 1, 1};

   nextState[] := (state = step[state]);
   nextState];
```

Which you use like this:

```
next = makeLFSR[];
next[]
next[]
next[]
```

{0, 1, 0, 1}
{1, 0, 1, 0}
{1, 1, 0, 1}

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what type, but based on your recent questions it appears a basic LFSR over *GF(2)* is what you're poking at:

```
lfsrBits = With[{coeff = #1, init = #2, iter = #3, l = Length@#2}, 
                 Nest[Flatten[{#, Mod[#[[-l ;;]].coeff, 2]}] &, init, iter - l]] &;

lfsrBits[{1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, 20]

(* {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0} *)
```

Arguments to *lfsrBits* are the coefficients of the connection polynomial, the initial state, and number of bits to generate.

Comment: Here is more information since I am not sure what to change in what you have given above to accomodate for it. I will be using this LFSR to encrypt text. This text will be encoded over $Z_128$ (assuming a change is needed for this?) and the LFSR will need to work with the binary representation of the text. (which I think is ok already)